# Prevent rsync from overwriting already copied files

Tags: backup, rsync

We used to do backup on (source) server to another server by running rsync on source server. On recieving server there is rsyncd running and its config changed each day pointing to different dir (dir per day). The idea behind is that we'll have full filetree for each day. On recieving server there is also `write only = yes` option set, so sending part can not retrive files back.

The concern is, if hacker would break into source server then he'll be able to rewrite all of the filetree with empty files. **Is there any way I can tell rsyncd not to rewrite files existing on recieving end?**

All I can find on topic is about 'how to use rsync options not to send files that are already sent', but in case of hacker this won't be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In case of hacker, use filesystem snapshots (e.g. Btrfs or ZFS snapshots) instead of daily directories. It will prevent such attacks because rsyncd will literally not have privileges to delete old snapshots, as well as being more efficient with disk usage on the backup server (the same file snapshotted 30 times will only occupy 1x the disk space).

Comment: Nice solution, and it was among others to consider but yet we can not afford it now, since backup machine is set up already and it's hard to change its without backup data lost. But yes, this seems to be niciest idea.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pushing backups from the source server to the backups server, consider turning it around. Control and manage the backups process from the backups server. This gives you the following advantages:

- You can lock down the backups server so that it is entirely inaccessible from the source server
- Optionally, you could allow files to be retrieved by the source server from any backup, but be aware this would then give a potential route in to the backups server from the source server
- You provide an extra layer of protection by separating access to the source server from access to the backups server
- The backups process becomes less complicated because you don't need to rewrite the `rsyncd` configuration file each day

(Some of these reasons overlap, I know.) The `rsnapshot` tool can be used to manage this, should you not already be using it.

For implementation reasons you might need to run `rsyncd` on the source server. That's fine as you can lock it down with `iptables` or an external firewall, and then require a username/password to access data. However, remember that the `rsyncd` protocol does not encrypt its traffic, so could be sniffed from either end of the conversation or from any node between.

If the backups server is suitably locked down you might decide to allow it to log in across ssh to the source server as root, so that it can access all files on the machine. This gives you an encrypted transport layer for the backup data. However, here should you choose to do this ensure that the backups server really is tightly locked down and not at all generally accessible as you are effectively granting anyone - or anything - with root access on the backups server full access to your source server.